# How to send message to all subviews of a certain kind in view IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uikit, subview

hey guys i have  64 mini views added in one boardView.I want to send message(call instance method ) to every one of these subviews to update it's state without having one additional array holding these views   in the parent view. parent view is my own subclass of UIView. is there's a way to reference them all ? any advices ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be cleaner to use the Observer pattern. Google it. Or try using NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine why you wouldn't want to just group those all into an array, but you could loop through the views and use `isKindOfClass:` to check them. For example:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[MyCustomClass class]])
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if `subview` had a type of `UIView *` instead of `id` since the `subviews` method gives an array of `UIView` objects.

Comment: Good call, I was just trying to be really generic with it. I updated my answer to use `UIView *`

Comment: nice thanks guys it's perfect i also make  a cast             [(myclassCell*)IteratedSubView update]; and it worked like a charm :)